# Dyanmic Shortest Path

Tags: algorithm, graph, shortest-path

Your friends are planning an expedition to a small town deep in the Canadian north
next winter break. They’ve researched all the travel options and have drawn up a directed
graph whose nodes represent intermediat destinations and edges represent the reoads betweeen
them.
In the course of this, they’ve also learned that extreme weather causes roads in this part of
the world to become quite slow in the winter and may cause large travel delays. They’ve
found an excellent travel Web site that can accurately predict how fast they’ll be able to
travel along the roads; however, the speed of travel depends on the time of the year. More
precisely, the Web site answers queries of the following form: given an edge e = (u, v)
connecting two sites u and v, and given a proposed starting time t from location u, the
site will return a value fe(t), the predicted arrival time at v. The web site guarantees that
1
fe(t) > t for every edge e and every time t (you can’t travel backward in time), and that
fe(t) is a monotone increasing function of t (that is, you do not arrive earlier by starting
later). Other than that, the functions fe may be arbitrary. For example, in areas where the
travel time does not vary with the season, we would have fe(t) = t + `e, where`e is the
time needed to travel from the beginning to the end of the edge e.
Your friends want to use the Web site to determine the fastest way to travel through the
directed graph from their starting point to their intended destination. (You should assume
that they start at time 0 and that all predictions made by the Web site are completely
correct.) Give a polynomial-time algorithm to do this, where we treat a single query to
the Web site (based on a specific edge e and a time t) as taking a single computational step.

```
    def updatepath(node):
        randomvalue = random.randint(0,3)
        print(node,"to other node:",randomvalue)
        for i in range(0,n):
            distance[node][i] = distance[node][i] + randomvalue

    def minDistance(dist,flag_array,n):
        min_value = math.inf
        for i in range(0,n):
            if dist[i] < min_value and flag_array[i] == False:
                min_value = dist[i]
                min_index = i
        return min_index

    def shortest_path(graph, src,n):
        dist = [math.inf] * n
        flag_array = [False] * n
        dist[src] = 0

        for cout in range(n):
            #find the node index that have min cost
            u = minDistance(dist,flag_array,n)
            flag_array[u] = True
            updatepath(u)
            for i in range(n):
                if graph[u][i] > 0 and flag_array[i]==False and dist[i] > dist[u] + graph[u][i]:
                    dist[i] = dist[u] + graph[u][i]
                    path[i] = u
        return dist
```

I applied Dijkstra algorithm but it is not correct ? What would i change in my algorithm to work it for dynamic changing edge.

Comment: Please do not just paste a full problem description for us to analyze, but instead provide a succinct and precise description of the problem you are facing and your attempts to solve it. There is no context to the posted code and no comments, so it is hard to follow what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: The problem is friends want to go for out for a picnic and they're traversing through different cities. The cost is number of hours it takes to travel from one city to another. But there is seasonal effect that would change the cost because of which path would change.                                                                         but dijakstra is works for static graph.

Comment: No, I mean, the problem is you have a weighted graph and you want to find the shortest path between two nodes, with the particularity that the weight of each edge in a path depends (i.e. is a positive and monotone function) on the summed weights of the previous edges.

Comment: Because of the constraints, Dijkstra's algorithm works fine, but of course you need to consider the time it takes to get to a vertex when you calculate the costs to travel from that vertex.  A quick look over your code suggests that you are simulating that. Your code is slow, but it looks like it works OK.  How do you know it's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Key points are that **function is monotonically increasing**. There is an algorithm which exploits this property and it is called **A***.

**Accumulated cost:** Your prof wants you to use two distances one is accumulated cost(this is simple the cost from previous added to the cost/time needed to move to the next node).

**Heuristic cost:** This is some predicted cost.

Disjkstra approach would not work because you are working with **heuristic cost/predicted** and **accumulated cost**.

Monotonically increasing means **h(A) <= h(A) + f(A..B)**.It simply says that if you move from node **A** to node **B** then the cost should not be less than the previous node (in this case A) and this is **heuristic + accumulated.** If this property holds then the first path which **A*** chooses is always the path to goal and it never needs to backtrack.

**Note:** The power of this algorithm is totally base on how you predict value.

If you underestimate the value that will be corrected with accumulated value but if you overestimate the value it will chose wrong path.

**Algorithm:**

```
Create  a Min Priority queue.
insert initial city in q.
```

`while(!pq.isEmpty() && !Goalfound)
   Node min = pq.delMin()     //this should return you a cities to which your 
                                    distance(heuristic+accumulated is minial).
   put all succesors of min in pq      // all cities which you can reach, you 
                                              can better make a list of visited 
                                                cities s that queue will be 
                                                  efficient by not placing same 
                                                  element twice.
Keep doing this and at the end you will either reach goal or your queue will be empty`

**Extra**

Here i implemented a 8-puzzle-solve using A*, it can give you an idea about how costs are defined and ho it works.

`

```
private void solve(MinPQ<Node> pq, HashSet<Node> closedList) {
        while(!(pq.min().getBoad().isGoal(pq.min().getBoad()))){
            Node e = pq.delMin();
            closedList.add(e);
            for(Board boards: e.getBoad().neighbors()){
                Node nextNode = new Node(boards,e,e.getMoves()+1);
                if(!equalToPreviousNode(nextNode,e.getPreviousNode()))
                      pq.insert(nextNode);
               }
            }
        Node collection = pq.delMin();
            while(!(collection.getPreviousNode() == null)){
                this.getB().add(collection.getBoad());
                collection =collection.getPreviousNode();
        }
            this.getB().add(collection.getBoad());
            System.out.println(pq.size());
    }
```

A link to [full](https://github.com/afrazsalim/Gegevens-en-algorithm/tree/master/8-Puzzle-solver/gna-practicum2-2014-2015/gna-practicum2-2014-2015/src/gna) code is here.

Comment: If suppose after reaching node B. the distance there is a change in cost due to seasonal effect. Would this algorithm work then ?

Comment: Yes because all the succesors of first node are in Queue and all you need is to update the cost in queue aswell if the costs change. Queue will automatically return minimal then.

Comment: Thanks for the help